# How to remove the footnote in Europass cv

Tags: footnotes, europasscv

I have seen that `notitle` helps in removing the title in Europass CV but not sure how to remove this in Europass CV. Any help?

[image: The below stated link must be removed]

Comment: I suspect the copyright notice is there for a good reason.
Edit: The documentation doesn't seem to give an option for that. You would probably have redefine some command used in the class, or change the class itself.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you did not tell us which version of europass you use (`europecv2013` or older `europecv`).

Both of them knew a command `\ecvfootnote` you can fill with the text you want

```
\ecvfootnote{For more information go to       % <=======================
  \url{http://europass.cedefop.eu.int}\\
  \textcopyright~European Communities, 2003.} % <=======================
```

or simply left it blank:

```
\ecvfootnote{} % <=======================
```

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[helvetica,openbib,totpages]{europecv}% europecv2013 europecv
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{url}

\ecvname{Surname, Name}
\ecvfootername{Name Surname}
\ecvaddress{House number, street name, postcode, city, country}
\ecvtelephone[(Remove if not relevant)]{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvfax{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvemail{\url{email@address.com} (Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvnationality{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvdateofbirth{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvgender{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvpicture[width=2cm]{example-image}
\ecvfootnote{} % <=======================


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[5pt]
\ecvitem{\large\textbf{Desired employment/ Occupational~field}}{\large\textbf{(Remove if not relevant)}}

\ecvsection{Work experience}
\ecvitem{Dates}{Add separate entries for each relevant post occupied, starting from the most recent. (Remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{Occupation or position held}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Main activities and responsibilities}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Name and address of employer}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Type of business or sector}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Education and training}

\ecvitem{Dates}{Add separate entries for each relevant course you have completed, starting from the most recent. (Remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{Title of qualification awarded}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Principal subjects/Occupational skills covered}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Name and type of organization providing education and training}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Level in national or international classification\footnote{If appropriate.}}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Personal skills and~competences}

\ecvmothertongue[5pt]{Specify mother tongue}
\ecvitem{\large Other language(s)}{}
%\ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
\ecvlanguage{English}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}
\ecvlanguage{Deutsch}{\ecvCTwo}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvBOne}{\ecvATwo}
\ecvlanguage{Language}{}{}{}{}{}
%\ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]{(*)}

\ecvitem[10pt]{Language(s) certificates}{}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\textbf{English}}{Blafasel, Total score: 333, date: 2015-10-21}

\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Social skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Organisational skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Technical skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Computer skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Artistic skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Other skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{\large Driving licence(s)}{State here whether you hold a driving licence and if so for which categories of vehicle. (Remove if not relevant).}

\ecvsection{Additional information}
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{Include here any other information that may be relevant, for example contact persons, references, etc. (Remove heading if not relevant).}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{publications}
\ecvitem{}{\textbf{Publications}}
\ecvitem{}{\bibentry{pub1}}
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{\bibentry{pub2}}
\ecvitem{}{\textbf{Personal interests}}
\ecvitem{}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Annexes}
\ecvitem{}{List any item attached to the CV}
\end{europecv}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: wished result]

Comment: Works also for `texlive-europasscv` (Version: svn49703, Release: 19.fc31, Source RPM: texlive-2019-19.fc31.src.rpm) on Fedora Linux 31.